# ReplaceAll with pattern matching not working with list of lists

Tags: list-manipulation, function-construction, pattern-matching

**Abstract** This is just a learning exercise for me. I am trying to create a function that will take a list of vectors, multiply them by a constant if constant is given, and then add all vectors. If we have no constants then the list looks like this: `{list1, list2,...}`. However if we want to scale one or more vectors the list would look like this: `{{c1,list}, {c2,list}}`. I can get it to work with one list whether it has a constant or not but not for a list of lists.

```
u = {1, -2}; v = {2, -5}; c1 = 4; c2 = -3;
vec1 = {u, c1}; vec2 = {c2, v};
ReplaceAll[{vec1, vec2}, {x_List, c_} -> c  x] (* gives wrong values *)
vec1 /. {x_List, c_} -> c*x (* this works but not if x_List and c_ reordered *)
{c1*u, c2*v} (* this is the value I am seeking *)
```

Comment: You can use the pattern ` {x_List, c_?NumericQ} :> c  x` to prevent `ReplaceAll` from matching `c` to `vec2`. Or even `{x_List, c : Except[_List]} :> c  x` Also, it's better to use `RuleDelayed` (`:>`) for these kinds of replacements. The normal rule `->` will not work correctly if `x` has a value already.

Answer (score 2):

When you did

```
ReplaceAll[{vec1,vec2}, {x_List, c_} :> c x ]
(* {{-3, 6}, {8, -20}} *)
```

Then it took `x=vec1` and `c=vec2` which is not what you want. So it did `vec1 vec2` which is

```
vec1*vec2
(* {{-3,6},{8,-20}} *)
```

You can instead thread over the input

```
(ReplaceAll[#, {x_List, c_} :> c x] &) /@ {vec1, vec2}
(*  {{4, -8}, {-3, {2, -5}}}  *)
```

One way to find this out, is to actually insert Print statements, on the right side, like this

```
ReplaceAll[{vec1, vec2}, {x_List, c_} :> (Print["x=", x, " c=", c]; c x)]
```

The print does not affect the replacement, but useful to see what is being replaced. Then you would see the following

[image]

In addition, if you do `Attributes[ReplaceAll]` you would see that `Listable` is not given as attribute of `ReplaceAll`

Comment: thank you so much it worked. but as I add a `Apply[Plus[...` to complete my function it works when not named but does not work when called by name (`vectorScalerPlus[vecs]`).


`c1 = 1; c2 = 2; c3 = 3;
u = {1, 1, 1}; v = {1, 1, 1}; w = {1, 1, 1};
vecs = {{c1, u}, v, {c3, w}}
Plus[c1 u, v, c3 w] (* seeking this value *)
Apply[Plus, (Replace[#, {c_, x_List} :> c x] &) /@ 
  vecs, {0}](* this works *)
vectorScalerPlus := 
  Apply[Plus, (Replace[#, {c_, x_List} :> c x] &) /@ vecs, {0}];
vectorScalerPlus[vecs](* does not work in classical function call *)`

Comment: I believe I may have inadvertantly typed a few hidden characters spoiling my function because when I tried to line up `Plus[c1 u, v, c3 w] (* seeking this value *) ` the comment insisted on dropping down to the next line even though it was a short line of characters. I also noticed large parenthesis forming at the `Apply[...` line of code and noticed a box entity I didn't mean to type. To fix these I reordered and retyped fresh line with comment and retyped offending areas of code but it is still buggy. Im not sure how to fix this.